# Group by in nested subquery

Tags: sql

I've got two tables:

```
Researcher (ResId, Fname, Gname)
Book (bookID, ResID*, Descr)
```

I need to use `IN` (one of the condition of my assignment) statement to show a list of researchers that have more than 5 books.

I've got the following SQL query that seems to be logic but it gives an error. The subquery on its own works just fine:

```
select  ResId, Fname
from Researcher
where ResId in
   (select Book.ResId, count(*)
   from Book
   group by Book.ResId
   having count(*) > 5
   )
```

Comment: Error messages exist for a purpose! If you have an error... post it! That would make everything a lot easier for everybody.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
where ResId in
   (select Book.ResId, count(*)
```

When you use `IN (Select...`, you can only select one column in the sub query.
Change the above to:

```
where ResId in
   (select Book.ResId
```

only.

Answer (score 1):

Does that work as expected?

```
Select  ResId, Fname
From Researcher r
Inner Join Book b on b.ResId = r.ResId
Group By r.ResId, r.FName
Having count(b.*) > 5
```

Comment: Hi James, I need to use "IN" statement. Otherwise the answer is not counted

Answer (score 1):

Only remove `count(*)` like this:

```
select  ResId, Fname
from Researcher
where ResId in
   (select Book.ResId 
   from Book
   group by Book.ResId
   having count(*) > 5
   )
```